# Is Android KeyStore Preserved During Upgrade To PI?

Tags: android, upgrade, keystore, android-9.0-pie

A user of my Android app has upgraded their OS to Android 9.0 (API 28). It looks like the KeyStore value (type 'AndroidKeyStore') has been lost in the process.

We stored a private key in the store this way, although it's hard to tell without logs in this case and reproducing it also tricky (simulator - not possible I think, and I don't yet have a new device) - the app created a new key when it was first run after this upgrade.

eg:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(SecurityConstants.KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
ks.load(null);
KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry(alias, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keystore contents should be fully preserved during upgrade.  In fact, this is essential, because some important system keys are protected by AndroidKeyStore.  Even the device encryption keys are protected by Keymaster, the low-level component of AndroidKeyStore.

If the user removed and reinstalled your app, that would cause the key to be lost.  Or if the app changed UID via some other mechanism.  And, of course, if your key was authentication-bound to a fingerprint or other biometric, enrolling a new fingerprint could have destroyed it (depending on key configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I think the KeyStore is actually not misbehaving in this scenario. We have this in the manifest:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

... which I think is maybe causing us to lose all our persisted data during the upgrade.

Comment: I don't think so.  Backup is about backing up your data for restoration onto a new device.  It shouldn't affect upgrades.

Comment: Right. I'm in clutching-at-straws stage.